# Find all unmerged files/elements in ClearCase

Tags: merge, clearcase

We use ClearCase where I work and I'm trying to figure out how to find any files that have been modified but not merged up.  We have a main branch at the very top level in ClearCase, and this is where the final source code changes are merged to and where we do our formal release builds from.  We then have an integration branch under main where integration issues are worked out.  When we get everything working and tested in the integration branch, we merge the integration branch up to main.  For individual feature implementations and bug fixes, we create a new branch (usually named after an action, feature, or bugfix) off of the integration branch and work the issue.  When we are done with it, we merge that change up to the integration branch.

I was wondering if anybody knew of a command or a way to see what files are modified in the feature/bug fix branches but were not merged back up to the integration branch.  I've been looking around but I can't seem to find a way to do it.  I would like to be able to run the command and have it tell me all files that have been modified on all of the sub-branches but not merged up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the source and destination branches (topic detailed in [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462886/find-all-unmerged-files-elements-in-clearcase/7463075#7463075), which I have upvoted), then don't forget the [query primitive](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm) **merge**:

```
merge (from-location , to-location)
```

> In all cases, `TRUE` if the element to which the object belongs has a **merge hyperlink** (default name: `Merge`) connecting the `from-location` and `to-location`.
>   You can specify either or both locations with a branch pathname or a version selector.
>   Specifying a branch produces `TRUE` if the merge hyperlink involves any version on that branch.
>   The branch pathname must be complete (for example, `/main/rel2_bugfix`, not `rel2_bugfix`).

[This thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=3556504) illustrates that query in action:

> > How is it possible to find all the elements on a specific branch that are checked in and not merged away?

```
cleartool find \\view\administration\ProjectVOB \
   -branch "brtype(HNH-372452) && \
   !merge(...\HNH-372452\LATEST,...\main-372452\LATEST)" -print

\\view\administration\ProjectVOB\Com-API\Dll\COMFrontendDll\Mmi.cpp@@\main\HNH-372452
\\view\administration\ProjectVOB\geometry\geochain\geocutterloc.cpp@@\main\HNH-372452
```

That "merge hyperlink" is the red arrow you see in version tree:
(see article "[Versioning and parallel development of requirements](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/08/0923_moller-karlsen-knodlseder/)")

[image: red arrow in version tree]

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you use `ct findmerge` to find files to merge from one branch or view into the current view (assuming `ct` is an alias for `cleartool`).

I think you would have to identify all the branches you are interested in and do a separate `ct findmerge` operation for each branch - for each destination branch.  That's complex.  You'd also want to be able to eliminate many branches which are known to be fully merged.  You can annotate a branch to indicate that it is fully merged.

So, I don't think there is a simple, single command to do this job.

---

You need to decide which branches are targets that you're concerned about.  These would be your integration branch(es).  Presumably, you have a fairly small list of these.

For each of those target branches, you need to decide which work branches are relevant to that integration branch.  This is the tricky part; there is no easy way to determine whether a particular bug fix or feature branch is relevant to that integration branch using information in the VOBs; it is really only known by the users.

You then need a script that does (in outline):

```
for int_branch in $(list_relevant_integration_branches)
do
    ...create view with tag $tag for $int_branch...
    ct setcs -f $(cspec_for_integration_branch $int_branch) $tag
    ct setview -exec "find_outstanding_merges_for_integration_branch $int_branch" $tag
done
```

where `find_outstanding_merges_for_integration_branch` looks a bit like:

```
vob_list=$(list_relevant_vobs)
for mrg_branch in $(list_relevant_merge_branches $int_branch)
do
    echo
    echo "Merges from $mrg_branch to $int_branch"
    ct findmerge $vob_list -fversion .../$mrg_branch/LATEST -print
done
```

Note that this command assumes (a) the current view is appropriate for the target, and (b) the integration branch name is passed as an argument.

You can get fancy and decide how to handle automatic or graphical merges instead of `-print`.  The hard part is still the unwritten commands such as `list_relevant_integration_branches` and `list_relevant_vobs`.  These might be simple:

```
# list_relevant_integration_branches
cat <<EOF
integration_branch_version_3_0
integration_branch_version_3_1
integration_branch_version_4_0
EOF

# list_relevant_vobs
cat <<EOF
/vobs/mainproject
/vobs/altproject
/vobs/universal
EOF
```

Or they might be considerably more complex.  (If you only have one VOB, then your life is much simpler; the systems we work with have 20-odd VOBs visible in the cspec.)

The other unwritten script is `list_relevant_merge_branches`.  I don't know whether there's a simple way to write that.  If you define and apply appropriate attribute types (`ct mkattype`, `ct mkattr`) when the development branches are created (perhaps a 'target integration branch' attribute type, an enumeration type), you could use that to guide you.  That leaves you with a retrofit problem; how to get the correct attribute onto each existing working branch.  You also need a separate attribute to identify branches that no longer need merge scrutiny, unless you decide that the absence of a 'target integration branch' attribute means 'no need to scrutinize any more'.  That reduces the retrofit problem to adding the target integration branch to those branches that still need merging; by default, all existing branches will be deemed fully merged.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I shouldn't have restricted it to 'one command'.  Would it maybe be possible to have a script that can do this?